# DevExpress - Select multiple checkboxes in TreeList

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

Let's say if I have a TreeList of 2 groups, teachers and students, there is a column of "Status". I'm trying to implement a button to select all groups of teachers and students who are active.

[image]

This is what I have so far

```cs
public class MatchStatusOps : TreeListOperation
{
    private string fieldName;
    private string status;
    private TreeList helper;

    public TreeListMatchStatusOperation(string fieldName, string status,TreeList helper)
    {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        this.status = status;
        this.helper = helper;
    }

    public override void Execute(TreeListNode node)
    {
        String statusValue = Convert.ToString(node[fieldName]);
        if (statusValue.Equals(status))
            helper.SetNodeCheckState(node, CheckState.Checked, true);
    }
}
```

Then, I called it from my TreeList class

```cs
MatchStatusOps operation = new MatchStatusOps("Status","Active",this);
this.NodesIterator.DoOperation(operation);
```

I cannot make the check boxes selected, I think it may be because the node selected is the status nodes, not the checkbox nodes? Any ideas I could make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think it may be because the node selected is the status nodes, not the checkbox nodes

Those are not nodes, those are columns (usually bound by field name).  A node can contain any number of columns.

Further, this line of code ensures your operation is running across all nodes:

```
NodesIterator.DoOperation(operation);
```

The code below is based on an educated guess about your data source or code that populates the `TreeList` (if unbound) from the screenshot.

**Code:**

```
public class MatchStatusOps : TreeListOperation
{
    private readonly string fieldName;
    private readonly string status;
    private readonly string checkboxFieldName;

    public MatchStatusOps(string fieldName, string status, string checkboxFieldName)
    {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        this.status = status;
        this.checkboxFieldName = checkboxFieldName;
    }

    public override void Execute(TreeListNode node)
    {
        String statusValue = Convert.ToString(node[fieldName]);
        if (statusValue.Equals(status))
            node[checkboxFieldName] = true;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var operation = new MatchStatusOps("Status","Active","YourCheckboxFieldName");
NodesIterator.DoOperation(operation);
```

Note I'm setting a **column** on a given node to checked, not the node itself.

Confirmed working on my end with latest DevExpress version as of this writing.